# Windows 10 C# client application getting SecurityNegotiationException

Tags: c#

I have a Windows 10 C# application that contacts a web service hosted on a Windows Server 2016. The client application is set on a timer which calls the server back every 2 minutes. It uses a client certificate from a smart card to establish mutual authentication.

The initial connection to the web service works every time. Every following connection fails. If I restart the application I can connect the first time then all subsequent connections fail. It is a basic hello world web service and a simple windows form that calls it.

The exception I'm getting is "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority "

Here's where it gets strange. If I change the timer to 30 seconds it works every time.

If I turn on System.Net tracing it works every time with the 2 minute timer.

Please Help!

EDIT:
I set System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime well above my timer. This fixed the issue for our hello world test application but not for our production application.

EDIT:
I was able to get this timeout to work in our production application. In our production application it was still set up as a web service. After converting it to a service reference setting this timeout has been working properly. Why is this? Is this a bug in the ServicePointManager? This still does not seem like an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

CRL or CSP retrieval is likely timing out. The retrieval happens with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380269(v=vs.85).aspx. Use CryptoAPI debugging to confirm this - http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=297.

Comment: I added the CryptoAPI debugging to both the client and the server. When it fails to establish the secure channel, I only get logs on the client side. There are no errors in the logs and they look exactly the same as the logs when it works.

Comment: I even went ahead and removed AIA and CDP from our certificates. I regenerated the client and server certificate and set ServerCertificateValidationCallback to always return true and it still always fails on the second attempt. I think that completely removes it being an issue with CDP.